# How to export custom table data in csv

Tags: magento2

I have created custom table and added some columns and data.I need to export the custom table data in csv format in magento 2.How to do this, can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: where you want to export data in CSV format frontend or backend

Comment: In custom admingrid page